# How to update elements in a View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, view, controller

I'm fairly new to Objective-C development.
In my first app built from scratch, I'd like to draw a circle that increases its size as time runs.
The problem is that I've been able to move the circle through the screen, but can't seem to update its properties so it gets bigger or smalles.

Thing goes like this:

```
CCircle class

@interface CCircle : CShapes

@property float radius;
@property float startAngleRadians;
@property float endAngleRadians;
```

In the first view controller (ShapesViewController.m):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    (...)
    CCircle* circle = [[CCircle alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    circle.radius = 40;
    circle.startAngleRadians = M_PI;
    circle.endAngleRadians = 2*M_PI;
    circle.tag = 1;
    [self.view addSubView:circle];

    //I also schedule an update method, so that it is called every 1 seconds.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTmieInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCircle) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Also in ShapesViewController.m, the update method:

```
- (void) updateCircle
{
    CCircle *circle = [self.view viewWithTag:1];

    //Now here: if I do this: the circle will "move" through the screen
    CGRect frame = circle.frame;
    frame.origin.x += 5;
    [circle setFrame:frame];

    //However, if I try to change the circle properties, I don't know what to do so 
    //that affects the circle. In this case, the circle will move through the screen, 
    //but I keep seeing always the same size(radius).
    circle.radius += 5;

    //I've tried the following (of course, not all at the same time):
    //[self.vew addSubview:circle];
    //[self.view sendSubviewToBack:circle];
    //[self.view sendSubviewToFront:circle];
    //[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    //[self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Any help on what am I doing wrong, and what should I do to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: You updated a property of `circle`, not `self.view`, so I'd think calling `setNeedsDisplay` on `circle` would be worth a try.

Comment: Glad it worked! I added that as a formal answer to help resolve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You updated a property of `circle`, not `self.view`, so you need to call `setNeedsDisplay` on `circle`.

Answer (score 0):

After drawing the circle, you have to update your view.

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

I think that'll do it.

Comment: I've already tried that (it's actually the first thing I tried), and doesn't work.